# In Visual Studio Code How do I merge between two local branches?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code it seems that I am only allowed to push, pull and sync. There is documented support for merge conflicts but I can't figure out how to actually merge between two branches. The Git command line within VSC (press F1) only facillitates a subset of commands:

[image: eGit options available in VSCode]

Attempting to pull from a an alternate branch or push to an alternate branch yields:

[image: git Command throttling]

Here's the documentation on VSCode's Git
    [Visual Studio Code Git Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy8qz.png)

What am I overlooking?

Comment: Are you sure you have checked everywhere, q.v. [this blog](https://jeremybytes.blogspot.sg/2014/12/getting-used-to-git-in-visual-studio.html?m=1) which discusses how to merge two branches?

Comment: That's Visual Studio and not Visual Studio Code which is a separate application altogether. More info: VisualStudio.com and https://code.visualstudio.com

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Update June 2017 (from [VSCode 1.14](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_14))

The ability to merge local branches has been added through [PR 25731](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/25731) and commit [89cd05f](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/commit/89cd05f877231e54c8c099142f03689d9feff451): accessible through the "`Git: merge branch`" command.
And [PR 27405](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/27405) added handling the diff3-style merge correctly.

[Vahid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889607/vahid)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46747053/6309) mention 1.17, but that [September release](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_17) actually added nothing regarding merge.
Only the 1.18 October one added [Git conflict markers](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_18#_git-conflict-marker-detection)

[image: https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_18/merge.png]

From 1.18, with the combination of merge command (1.14) *and* merge markers (1.18), you truly can do local merges between branches.

---

Original answer 2016:

The [Version Control doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol) does not mention merge commands, only merge status and conflict support.

Even the [latest 1.3 June release](https://code.visualstudio.com/Updates#_june-release-summary) does not bring anything new to the VCS front.

This is supported by [issue 5770](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5770) which confirms you cannot use VS Code as a git `mergetool`, because:

> > Is this feature being included in the next iteration, by any chance?
>
> Probably not, this is a big endeavour, **since a merge UI needs to be implemented**.

That leaves the actual merge to be initiated from command line only.

Comment: Well that sucks!

Comment: Good suggestion but it's command line or Git Gui/Extensions for me, but it would be cool to have this built into Visual Studio Code as it is in regular Visual Studio.

Comment: Merging branches is day to day task for me. We need support for merging in VSCode.

Comment: @JonathanRamos, There are tools for everything, VSCode focuses on your needs to code, you need to look for a Git specific tool if you are a power user. It is possible that MS will introduce this feature in the future but there are other alternatives at the moment.

Comment: Would be nice a feature like the one in Visual Studio Community

Comment: @HelmutGranda you are right. VSCode allowed me to set Git Bash as default terminal so i can merge from there. That is a better aproach.

Comment: This can now be accomplished within native VsCode (see Vahid's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46747053/91189)

Comment: @JosephGabriel Thank you. It is actually from VSCode 1.14 (June 2017), not 1.17. I have updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 194):

You can do it without using plugins.

In the latest version of vscode that I'm using (1.17.0) you can simply open the branch that you want (from the bottom left menu) then press `ctrl+shift+p` and type `Git: Merge branch` and then choose the other branch that you want to merge from (to the current one)

Comment: After I select Git: Merge branch branch, will it commit automatically?

Comment: @JyotiPrasadPal yes you just need to `git: push/sync`

Comment: 2024 update: this option is now called "Git: Merge..."

Answer (score 52):

Actually you can do with VS Code the following:

[image: Merge Local Branch with VS Code]

Comment: For clarity, I'd like to add: FIRST you need to move (`checkout`) to the branch that you want to bring changes **into**; this can be done by clicking the branch name in the bottom-left of the `Status Bar` (it has a little source control branch icon next to it). SECOND: do as depicted in the image (`Branch` > `Merge Branch...`). THIRD: in the menu that appears select the branch that you want to take changes **from**.

Comment: Hi @BuzzB this comment really helped. Thank you.

Comment: Someone should edit the above comment into the answer as it's a pretty important note.

Answer (score 31):

I had the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44543755/vscode-merge-one-branch-into-another), so I created [Git Merger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shaharkazaz.git-merger#review-details).
hope this helps :)

Answer (score 8):

I found this extension for VS code called [Git Merger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shaharkazaz.git-merger).  It adds `Git: Merge from` to the commands.

Comment: The guy 2 comments above literally wrote it X)

Comment: *person 2 comments above