# vscode - Merge one branch into another

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to merge one branch into another using the vscode interface and not the terminal? or is there any extension that makes this possible?
using vscode v1.13.0
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your platform?

Comment: My platform is Mac OS

Comment: You can try using Git Extensions it originated as a Windows Only git graphic front end (a very good graphic front end). It can now be run on Linux and Mac using Mono, but I personally haven't used it. It has the best branch visualisations I've seen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have created an extension which is available under the name: [Git Merger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shaharkazaz.git-merger) in the vscode marketplace.

Comment: by interface, does he mean only when using shortcut key ctrl + shift + p? I couldn't find what changes in the source control was added when I installed it in VS code

Answer (score 11):

## Use `Git: merge branch` command

> VSCode now has built-in branch merge support.
>   see [In Visual Studio Code How do I merge between two local branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648772/in-visual-studio-code-how-do-i-merge-between-two-local-branches)

Press `Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+P` (Or `View` > `Command Palette...`) and look for `Git: merge branch`.

You select the branch to merge from (if you have a workspace open, the command lets you choose the project within the workspace).
Conflict management is also implemented, highlighting the Git conflict markers (see link above).
The branch gets merged with the commit message "Merged branch '[branchname]'"

Comment: The problem I've had with this in VSCODE is if you switch branches to your target in say a git submodule, the whole UI moves down after a second or two (in a large repo), making it disorienting/hard to sometimes remember what you were merging from.  I've had to stop using the UI to merge in my current repo because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays (2017-06-14) you can't, there is no extension to do so in VSCode. If you have time and skills, you can try to write your own extension, you're probably not the only one to want a feature like that, so you'll find contributors if you host it on Github for example.

You'll use the terminal a bit more. Sorry.