# "Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge" Merge two branches locally via Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to merge two branches locally. but have the error below:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        Main.txt
    Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
    Aborting
```

**Background**

I downloaded two branches from a Git repo, the structure of it below:

**'Main' Branch:**

Main.txt

**'Second' Branch**

Main.txt

In VS code, 'Second' branch is checked out currently.

I made changes to the *Main.txt* in the 'Second' branch locally in VS Code, which has conflicts with the local version of the Main.txt file in the 'Main' branch. I **stashed** the changes of Second's Main.txt.

**Merge branches locally**
I tried to merge the currently checkout 'Second' branch  to the 'Main' branch by following below:
[image]
but I get the error below.

**Full Error:**

```
[2022-06-07T13:56:57.959Z] > git merge main [126ms]
[2022-06-07T13:56:57.959Z] error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    Main.txt
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
[2022-06-07T13:59:31.068Z] > git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\userName\repos\myApp2\myApp\Home.txt [210ms]
[2022-06-07T13:59:31.080Z] > git ls-files --stage -- C:\Users\userName\repos\myApp2\myApp\Home.txt [232ms]
[2022-06-07T13:59:31.164Z] > git symbolic-ref --short HEAD [152ms]
[2022-06-07T13:59:31.229Z] > git cat-file -s xxx [150ms]
[2022-06-07T13:59:31.244Z] > git cat-file -s xxx [155ms]
[2022-06-07T13:59:31.334Z] > git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/Second refs/remotes/Second [160ms]
[2022-06-07T13:59:31.511Z] > git remote --verbose [160ms]
[2022-06-07T13:59:31.526Z] > git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname) [183ms]
[2022-06-07T13:59:31.663Z] > git config --get commit.template [125ms]
```

Again, I have stashed the changes as shown on the screenshot.

**Update**

Is it possible to resolve conflicts via the UI in VS code instead? Like in Visual Studio, I can merge local branches, and resolve conflicts before merging them.

Thanks @Sunshine for providing the command answer.

**Ref:**

[In Visual Studio Code How do I merge between two local branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648772/in-visual-studio-code-how-do-i-merge-between-two-local-branches)

Answer (score 0):

After working on the "second" branch :

```
git add .
git commit -m "changes to main.txt" #(for example) or you can just do git stash
```

After that if you want to merge the main branch into the second one:

```
git merge main-branch
```

Then if you have conflicts while trying to merge, you will have to solve them, then save and commit.

Also, think about rebasing your second branch :

```
git rebase main -i
```

and eventually you can solve eventual conflicts and then :

```
git rebase --continue
```

(just read the instructions while rebasing, it will guide you)

Comment: Is it possible to do it via the UI in VS code instead? Sorry I forgot to state this. Because I expect to use UI to resolve conflicts like in Visual Studio.

Comment: pls see my added update at the bottom of OP.

Comment: I see. Actually I don't use VS for this purpose. Try to fix this with these command lines for now so you won't be blocked and then practice more in further time with VS Code.